# Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить find запрос

Tags: linux, grep, find

Проблема: нужно вывести в файл список исполняемых файлов, которые содержат некую строку.
Написала команду так:
find dir/ -type -f -not -perm 0644 -exec grep -ril 'string' {} ; > output.txt

Но мне надо не только с 644, а например, еще 755 или 700 (то есть чтоб файл был исполняемым). Можно это как-то в запрос добавить?

Comment: `$ find -type f -executable`

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, нашла ответ:

```
find dir/ -type -f  -perm -u=x -exec grep -ril 'string' {} ; > output.txt
```